# Epub Tag Search

Tags: vb.net, epub

Anyone knows how to read an **Epub file** and able to search and locate the tags?
im using VB.Net, and I dont have any idea how to read an EPub.

Or Just help me to unzip or extract a certain file

these are my codes

```
Dim ZipToUnpack As String = txtPath.Text
Dim TargetDir As String = txtTXT.Text
Console.WriteLine("Extracting file {0} to {1}", ZipToUnpack, TargetDir)
Using zip1 As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(ZipToUnpack)
'AddHandler zip1.ExtractProgress, AddressOf MyExtractProgress
Dim a As ZipEntry
For Each a In zip1
a.Extract(TargetDir, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
Next
MsgBox("Done")
getFiles()
End Using


For j As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
Dim k As StreamReader = New StreamReader(New FileStream(Path.Combine(ListView1.Items(j).Tag, ListView1.Items(j).Text), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
k.ReadLine()
```

Can you help me whats the next step how to read all the html and count the img tags

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB#Version_3.0_.28current_version.29

Comment: still dont have any idea how to read it to my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps you'll want to take, in a language-agnostic fashion:

1. Unzip the .epub file
2. Read the META-INF/container.xml file, to find the rootfile tag. This gives you the location of the .opf file that declares the contents of the package. (I'll refer to it as content.opf, but it may have another name.)
3. Read & parse content.opf (it's XML too), and make a list of every file and path in the `<manifest>` section. This is a list of every file within the package.
4. For each of the .xhtml files in that manifest list (i.e. files with a media-type "application/xhtml+xml"), parse the HTML, looking for `<img>` tags.